# HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority]

Tags: spring-security

jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Request processing failed: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority]

When sending an http request using objectMapper to an object inherited from userDetails, an error occurs in GrantAuthority.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.